# Div take image size and div placed in empty space in page

Tags: html, css

Hello i want to make that my div size changing depending on image size. Below image there is a box for text, i want to make that text box do not get bigger in width that image but instead change the height. Also how to get that my divs are placed in pages free places.
This is what i have so far:
[image: This is what i have so far, as you see images are placed in line:]
As you can see text field change div's width, and div's are placed in line, but i need to get them in free palces as an secound image.

Here is style want i want to make:
[image: Here is style want i want to make]

My Css:

```
#figure2 {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.7em;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: white;
    font-size: xlarge;
}
#figure2 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: large;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<% loop $Images.Sort('SortOrder') %>
<a href="$Top.WebsiteLinkHyper">
<div id="figure2">
    $Tag 
<h3>$Title</h3>
</div>
</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

Sorry guys for bad English, not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to elements with text the following CSS rules:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

It will break your text to new line when it's needed.

Example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
}

p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

If you want to break long words too, you can use the following rules:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

Another example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
}

p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help i manage all by my self.  Made everything with javascript